# Java Open CV 3.4.2 how to extract different channels from Mat Object?

Tags: java, python, opencv, migration

at the moment I am trying to port a Python program which uses Open CV to Java.

This is the original Python code I am trying to translate:

```
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev, next, flow, pyr_scale, levels, winsize, iterations, poly_n, poly_sigma, flags)
u=flow[...,0]
v=flow[...,1]
```

In Java (using org.bytedeco.javacpp), calculating the optical flow is quite straightforward but I am having trouble calculating the respective *u* and *v* variables.

Supposing the following Java code:

```
calcOpticalFlowFarneback(image1, image2, flow, pyr_scale, levels, winsize, iterations, poly_n, poly_sigma, flags);
```

If I am not mistaking any informations about the flow *Mat* Object:

> the flow matrix contains the gradient of the movement between 2 frames. for each pixel location in the original frame, the channels contain dx and dy, so that prev_x + dx = cur_x, and prev_y + dy = cur_y. - [calcopticalflowfarneback answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/91820/flow-in-calcopticalflowfarneback/)

So in order to extract the *u* and *v* vectors, which correspond to dx and dy respectively (correct me if I am being silly), I need to split the two different channels of the *Mat* flow object.

How can I do this? I have tried a few approaches without success up to this moment. It seems a lot has changed in the latest *opencv* versions and previous answers on this page have not helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it last week and forgot to answer this question.

The [*extractChannel* function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gacc6158574aa1f0281878c955bcf35642) was able to solve this problem very easily:

```
    Mat U = new Mat();
    Mat V = new Mat();
    extractChannel(flow, U, 0);
    extractChannel(flow, V, 1);
```

Really sorry for the silly question but I could not find anything similar here.